# show data of simulated kinect in rviz

Tags: rviz, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a question, i used simulated huskey robot in ros, and i added a kinect on it, and huskey package has a launcher for rviz, but in rviz husky hasn't kinect on it, please let me know what should i do? how can i add simulated kinect that is on robot also to rviz and getting data of it in rviz?!
Thank you.

for adding kinect to base.urdf.xacro of huskey i used these tags:

```
  <gazebo>
<include>
        <uri>model://kinect</uri>
        <pose>0.25 0 0.42 0 0 0</pose>
      </include>
      <joint name="centercam" type="revolute">
        <child>kinect::link</child>
        <parent>base_footprint</parent>
        <axis>
          <xyz>1 1 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <upper>0</upper>
            <lower>0</lower>
          </limit>
        </axis>
      </joint>
</gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90806/show-data-of-simulated-kinect-in-rviz/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add the kinect to the urdf? Than it should be visible on the robot model.
The data you can view by adding an Pointcloud viewer in Rviz and point it to the appropriate topic.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2013-10-16**:
thank you man, i added kinect as you can see in main question to base.urdf.xacro for huskey robot. but in rviz i son't have any thing about it, i think it's because i used gazebo tag, i am not sure, can you help me?!!!

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-10-16**:
It really depends on your gazebo version which one works, which version do you run? Try some different Kinect implementations in gazebo.

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2013-10-16**:
Thank you again, my Ros is hydro and gazebo is 1.9.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-10-18**:
Then try this one:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#Openni_Kinect